# Does my function vertex and edge adding not insert data to STL container?

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search

I tried to implement a graph in C++. When I debugged Graph::addEdge(1, 3) function, it showed that it just added an edge containing 2 vertexes (Edge::srcVertex id 1 and Edge::destVertex id 3) but left other properties of Vertex instances from Graph::allEdges, such as every edge containing that vertex and its adjacent vertexes. I attempted to solve it many times but failed. I'm grateful for your assistance.

Main program:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Graph.h"
#include "Traverse.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Graph<int> graph(false);
    graph.addEdge(1, 3);
    graph.addEdge(1, 2);
    graph.addEdge(2, 3);

    Traverse<int> traverse;
    traverse.DFS(graph, 1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Graph implementation:

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Vertex;
template <typename T>
class Edge;
template <typename T>
class Graph;

template <typename T>
class Vertex {
    int id;
    T data{};
    std::list<Edge<T>> edges;
    std::list<Vertex<T>> adjacentVertex;

public:
    Vertex(int id) : id(id) {}

    int getID() const { return this->id; }

    void setData(const T data) { this->data = data; }
    T getData() { return this->data; }

    void addAdjacentVertex(Edge<T> &edge, Vertex<T> &vertex) {
        this->edges.push_back(edge);
        this->adjacentVertex.push_back(vertex);
    }
    std::list<Vertex<T>> &getAdjacentVertex() { return this->adjacentVertex; }

    std::list<Edge<T>> &getEdges() { return this->edges; }

    int getDegree() const { return this->edges.size(); }

    bool operator<(const Vertex<T> &vertex) const {
        return this->id < vertex.id;
    }

    bool operator==(const Vertex<T> &vertex) const {
        if (this->id == vertex.id && this->data == vertex.data) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Edge {
    bool isDirected;
    int weight;
    Vertex<T> srcVertex, destVertex;

public:
    Edge(Vertex<T>& srcVertex, Vertex<T>& destVertex, bool isDirected = false,
         int weight = 0)
        : srcVertex(srcVertex), destVertex(destVertex), isDirected(isDirected),
          weight(weight) {}

    Vertex<T> &getSrcVertex() { return this->srcVertex; }
    Vertex<T> &getDestVertex() { return this->destVertex; }

    int getWeight() const { return this->weight; }

    bool directed() const { return this->isDirected; }
    bool operator<(const Edge<T> &edge) const {
        return this->weight < edge.weight;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Graph {
    bool isDirected;
    std::list<Edge<T>> allEdges;
    std::map<int, Vertex<T>> allVertex;

public:
    Graph(bool isDirected = false) : isDirected(isDirected) {}

    void addEdge(int src, int dest, int weight = 0) {
        // Vertex<T> srcVertex = this->addSingleVertex(src);
        // Vertex<T> destVertex = this->addSingleVertex(dest);

        Vertex<T> srcVertex(src), destVertex(dest);

        Edge<T> edge(srcVertex, destVertex, isDirected, weight);
        srcVertex.addAdjacentVertex(edge, destVertex);

        if (!isDirected) destVertex.addAdjacentVertex(edge, srcVertex);
        allEdges.push_back(edge);

        allVertex.insert({src, srcVertex});
        allVertex.insert({dest, destVertex});
    }

    void addVertex(Vertex<T> &vertex) {
        if (allVertex.contains(vertex.getID())) return;

        allVertex.insert({vertex.getID(), vertex});
        for (auto &edge : vertex.getEdges()) allEdges.push_back(edge);
    }

    Vertex<T> addSingleVertex(int id) {
        if (allVertex.contains(id)) return allVertex.at(id);

        Vertex<T> v(id);
        allVertex.insert({id, v});
        return v;
    }

    void setDataForVertex(long id, T data) {
        if (!allVertex.contains(id)) return;

        Vertex<T> vertex = allVertex.at(id);
        vertex.setData(data);
    }

    std::list<Edge<T>> &getAllEdges() { return allEdges; }

    std::vector<Vertex<T>> getAllVertex() {
        std::vector<Vertex<T>> values;
        for (auto &[id, vertex] : allVertex) values.push_back(vertex);
        return values;
    }
};

#endif /* GRAPH_H */
```

Traverse.h:

```
#ifndef TRAVERSE_H
#define TRAVERSE_H

#include "Graph.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <set>

template <typename STLcontainer>
bool contains(const STLcontainer &container, const key_t &key) {
    return find(container.begin(), container.end(), key) != container.end();
}

template <typename T>
class Traverse {
    void DFSUtil(Vertex<T> &v, std::set<T> &visited) {
        visited.insert(v.getID());
        std::cout << v.getID() << ' ';

        for (auto &vertex : v.getAdjacentVertex()) {
            if (!visited.contains(vertex.getID())) DFSUtil(vertex, visited);
        }
    }

public:
    void DFS(Graph<T> &graph) {
        std::set<T> visited;
        for (auto &vertex : graph.getAllVertex())
            if (!visited.contains(vertex.getID())) DFSUtil(vertex, visited);
    }

    void DFS(Graph<T> &graph, int srcID) {
        if (!contains(graph.getAllVertex(), srcID)) {
            std::cout << srcID << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        std::set<T> visited;
        Vertex<T> srcVertex(srcID);
        DFSUtil(srcVertex, visited);
    }

    void DFS(Graph<T> &graph, Vertex<T> &srcVertex) {
        if (!contains(graph.getAllVertex(), srcVertex.getID())) {
            std::cout << srcVertex.getID() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        std::set<T> visited;
        DFSUtil(visited, srcVertex);
    }
    void BFS(Graph<int> &graph) {
        std::set<T> visited;
        std::list<Vertex<T>> q;

        for (Vertex<int> vertex : graph.getAllVertex()) {
            if (visited.contains(vertex.getID())) break;

            q.push_back(vertex);
            visited.add(vertex.getID());
            while (!q.empty()) {
                Vertex<T> vq = q.front();
                q.pop_front();
                std::cout << vq.getID() << " ";
                for (auto &v : vq.getAdjacentVertex())
                    if (!visited.contains(v.getID())) {
                        q.add(v);
                        visited.add(v.getID());
                    }
            }
        }
    }
};
#endif /* TRAVERSE_H */
```

[image: Debugging result]

Comment: Please don't tag your question as C if it doesn't contain C code. I don't understand your problem. Could you be clearer in your explanation of how you expect the program to behave vs how the program actually behaves. Try to write a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your `Edge` is storing copies of `Vertex`es. Then you modify the originals, expecting the copies to change. (There are probably other similar problems, but this one sticks out.)

Comment: `addEdge` should check if `allVertex` already contains the `Vertex` and modify the existing one instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using `std::list` instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: @Kerndog73 As you can see, I initialized srcVertex by `Vertex<T> srcVertex = this->addSingleVertex(src);` , if it's already existed, addSingleVertex() return a vertex from Graph::allVertex. So I think, it completed its job to modify the existing one.

Comment: @molbdnilo You pointed out the main problem existed here. I think in the `Edge::Edge()` constructor when I used `Vertex<T>& srcVertex`, both of the `Vertex<T>` instance would be changed simultaneously. So is there any solution for this?

Comment: @JohnWilliams Why is that commented out? I only saw the actual code (which has the problem I described)

Answer (score 0):

You are copying values, and then editing one copy, and hoping both change. This doesn't work.

You can instead have a single location for each object to reside, and references elsewhere

```
template <typename T>
using VertexRef = std::reference_wrapper<Vertex<T>>;

template <typename T>
using EdgeRef = std::reference_wrapper<Edge<T>>;

template <typename T>
class Vertex {
    int id;
    T data{};
    std::list<Edge<T>> edges;

public:
    Vertex(int id) : id(id) {}

    int getID() const { return id; }

    void setData(T data) { this->data = std::move(data); }
    T getData() { return data; }

    void addEdge(Vertex<T> & other, bool isDirected, int weight) {
        edges.emplace_back(*this, other, isDirected, weight);
    }

    std::list<VertexRef<T>> adjacentVertexs() { 
        std::list<VertexRef<T>> result;
        for (auto & edge : edges) { 
            result.push_back(edge.getDestVertex()); 
        }
        return result;
    }

    std::list<EdgeRef<T>> getEdges() { 
        return { edges.begin(), edges.end() };
    }

    int getDegree() const { return this->edges.size(); }

    bool operator<(const Vertex<T> & other) const {
        return (id < other.id);
    }

    friend bool operator<(const Vertex<T> & lhs, int rhs) const {
        return (lhs.id < rhs);
    }

    friend bool operator<(int lhs, const Vertex<T> & rhs) const {
        return (lhs < rhs.id);
    }

    bool operator==(const Vertex<T> & other) const {
        return (id == other.id) && (data == other.data);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Edge {
    bool isDirected;
    int weight;
    Vertex<T> & srcVertex;
    Vertex<T> & destVertex;

public:
    Edge(Vertex<T>& srcVertex, Vertex<T>& destVertex, bool isDirected = false,
         int weight = 0)
        : srcVertex(srcVertex), destVertex(destVertex), isDirected(isDirected),
          weight(weight) {}

    Vertex<T> &getSrcVertex() { return srcVertex; }
    Vertex<T> &getDestVertex() { return destVertex; }

    int getWeight() const { return weight; }

    bool directed() const { return isDirected; }
    bool operator<(const Edge<T> & other) const {
        return (weight < other.weight);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Graph {
    bool isDirected;
    std::set<Vertex<T>, std::less<>> vertexs;

public:
    Graph(bool isDirected = false) : isDirected(isDirected) {}

    void addEdge(int src, int dest, int weight = 0) {
        auto & srcVertex = getOrAddVertex(src);
        auto & destVertex = getOrAddVertex(dest);

        srcVertex.addEdge(destVertex, isDirected, weight);

        if (!isDirected) { 
            destVertex.addEdge(srcVertex, isDirected, weight); 
        }
    }

    Vertex<T> & getOrAddVertex(int id) {
        auto [it, ignore] = vertexs.emplace(id);
        return *it;
    }

    void setDataForVertex(int id, T data) {
        auto it = vertexs.find(id);
        if (it != vertexs.end()) {
            it->setData(data);
        }
    }

    std::list<EdgeRef<T>> getAllEdges() { 
        std::list<EdgeRef<T>> result;
        for (auto & vertex : vertexs) {
            edges = vertex.getEdges();
            result.insert(result.back, edges.begin(), edges.end());
        }
        return result;
    }

    std::vector<VertexRef<T>> getAllVertexs() {
        return { vertexs.begin(), vertexs.end() };
    }
};
```

Comment: @JohnWilliams `Graph<T>::addEdge` calls `Vertex<T>::addEdge` on the appropriate vertexes. The graph does not contain edges directly. `std::list<Edge<T>>` is a different type to `std::list<EdgeRef<T>>`. You may want `std::set<Edge<T>, /* some compare*/> edges;`, which is even more different.

Comment: 1. Why did you create `Vertex<T>::addEdge()` when `Graph<T>::addEdge()` already existed?
2. I wonder what is the point of your modified version of my `Vertex<T>::getEdges()` function? Returning `{ edges.begin(), edges.end() }` instead of `this->edges` directly?
3. Is there some way to preserve my code without changing its concept too much, or just modifying a little bit so I can get some experience to code afterwards, because this is the 5th time I rewrote my work.